# How can a fly be in the space of a roofless car, get out of the car space and get back in while the car is driving at the speed of 80mph?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, turbulence, vortex

I was driving in a cabriolet car at the speed of 80mph, while a fly flew in and out of the frame of the car. My question is, How can the fly leave the frame and get back in? Is it possible that it flies at 80mph?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about biology.

Comment: Maybe relevant. My cousin is a long-time pilot. He has heard of people who wished to have their ashes spread from an airplane. What a mess! The dust blows everywhere and they have a big cleanup job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fly is carried away within the turbulent motion of the air the moving car generates. Therefore, it stays close to the car (for a short while) and returns without actually having to fly at 80 mph. -> Answer to your second question: No!

A google search for "turbulence around car/obstacle/plane" gives colourful pictures of the wind field around moving objects.